# What are the types of class E airspace?

Tags: airspace, class-e-airspace

I don't quite understand the various categories of Class E airspace.

Comment: Which country or regulations are you asking about? And giving examples of the categories would help to understand your question better.

Answer (score 6):

Check out [this publication from the FAA](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2014.pdf)

> Class E airspace extends
>   upward from either the surface or a designated altitude to the overlying or adjacent controlled airspace. When designated
>   as a surface area, the airspace is configured to contain all
>   instrument procedures. Also in this class are federal airways,
>   airspace beginning at either 700 or 1,200 feet above ground
>   level (AGL) used to transition to and from the terminal or
>   en route environment, and en route domestic and offshore
>   airspace areas designated below 18,000 feet MSL. Unless
>   designated at a lower altitude, Class E airspace begins at
>   14,500 MSL over the United States, including that airspace
>   overlying the waters within 12 NM of the coast of the 48
>   contiguous states and Alaska, up to but not including 18,000
>   feet MSL, and the airspace above FL 600.

This image may help to visualize it

[image]
([source](http://www.cfinotebook.net/notebook/national-airspace-system/class-delta-airspace.php))

In more general terms its the airspace that covers most of the US below 18,000ft. Its the area where a lot of the General Aviation traffic lives (although some of it is making its way into the [flight levels these days](http://www.aopa.org/News-and-Video/All-News/2008/September/1/Mooney-Acclaim-Type-S-A-Piston-Rocket))

*Side note*: Depending on how you look at it class E airspace is bound to an upper limit of either 400,000 feet (76mi) which is what [NASA considers re-entry altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Outer_space) or what The Fédération Aéronautique Internationale defines as space starting at 62 miles so either one of those can be used as an upper bound for Class E (although officially the FAA does not define an upper bound). Re-entry point is where air drag comes into play so you would be hard pressed to get a plane over that altitude. Practically speaking the jet altitude record is held by the SR-71 Blackbird at 85,069ft and the Concorde pulls in at 60,039 ft for commercial flight.

Comment: Looks like we answered at about hte same time with the same info.

Comment: Haha i saw your answer right after I hit post.

Answer (score 2):

> Class E Airspace
>   If the airspace is not Class A, B, C, or D, and is controlled 
>   airspace, then it is Class E airspace. Class E airspace extends 
>   upward from either the surface or a designated altitude to the 
>   14-3
>   Figure 14-2.
>   An example of a prohibited area is Crawford, Texas.
>   overlying or adjacent controlled airspace. When designated 
>   as a surface area, the airspace is configured to contain all 
>   instrument procedures. Also in this class are federal airways, 
>   airspace beginning at either 700 or 1,200 feet above ground 
>   level (AGL) used to transition to and from the terminal or 
>   en route environment, and en route domestic and offshore 
>   airspace areas designated below 18,000 feet MSL. Unless 
>   designated at a lower altitude, Class E airspace begins at 
>   14,500 MSL over the United States, including that airspace 
>   overlying the waters within 12 NM of the coast of the 48 
>   contiguous states and Alaska, up to but not including 18,000 
>   feet MSL, and the airspace above FL 600.

You can find more about it here: https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/pilot_handbook/media/PHAK%20-%20Chapter%2014.pdf